# Saving Nested Models With Ember and HATEOAS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, hateoas

How can I achieve something like this `Ember 1.10.0` with Pod structure ? 
I am using `HATEOAS` with Ember. Both the models are under my pods directory.

So I am able to load the child and parent data from the server with this sample code.

The issue I am seeing is when I try to save using store

```
var newChild = store.createRecord('childModel', data);
store.save();
```

It uses the wrong url for saving. I expect it to use `/api/parentModel/{paren_id}/childModels` but instead it uses `/api/childModel` to save.

```
// uses the server url = /api/parentModel/{id}
// response : 
 {
   links : [
    child : '/api/parentModel/{paren_id}/childModels'
   ] 
 }
export default ParentModel = DS.Model.extend({
      'child' : DS.hasMany('childModel', {async: true})
})

export default ChildModel = DS.Model.extend({
      'someProperty' : DS.attr('string')
})
```

Comment: Which adapter do you use?

Comment: I am using `DS.RESTAdapter`

Comment: As far as I know, Ember Data does not support nested routes in endpoints. And it was always very tricky to implement and very unreliable. So I would recommend you to use plain endpoints structure in your backend application if it's possible.

Comment: Yes currently I decided to use that, But I was hoping there is some workaround with Ember.